# How to enable Line Number Shown in Visual Studio Build Output?

Tags: visual-studio, build

Running Visual Studio 2008 express,

notice that the output windows there it doesn't show the number such as: (example) while compiling, (even though running a project with multiple solution inside)

1 > adsfgafkgja;l
1 > asdfafas
1 > asdfaf
...
2 > asdfasf
2 > safas

trid a fresh installation, wonder why it isn't displaying the line number in the build output for my computer. seen that in other's computer. Having Line number in the Output windows would be helpful to keep track of the current file being compiled... it's gone, any methods to enable it?

Comment: Hmm never seen that feature..

Answer (score 1):

This is what you get when Visual Studio compiles multiple projects at the same time (dual core machines). Each project receives a number and every file being compiled gets the project number before the filename. Visual Studio does this automatically if you have more than one core, but it can be explicitly enabled/disabled:

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> maximum number of parallel project builds

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this does not work correctly for C# projects.
Warnings and errors are not numered.
Also not the line

```
Compile complete -- x errors, y warnings
```